# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) VisualStudio

Tags: android-ndk, visual-studio-2015, opengl-es-2.0

I've got very annoying error when trying to build my app.

Here is complete error stack

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\clang.exe  1
Error       undefined reference to 'glGetAttribLocation'    PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   70
Error       undefined reference to 'glCreateProgram'    PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   87
Error       undefined reference to 'glAttachShader' PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   91
Error       undefined reference to 'glAttachShader' PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   92
Error       undefined reference to 'glLinkProgram'  PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   93
Error       undefined reference to 'glGetProgramiv' PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   96
Error       undefined reference to 'glDeleteProgram'    PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   100
Error       undefined reference to 'glCreateShader' PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   111
Error       undefined reference to 'glShaderSource' PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   115
Error       undefined reference to 'glCompileShader'    PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   116
Error       undefined reference to 'glGetShaderiv'  PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   119
Error       undefined reference to 'glGetShaderiv'  PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   124
Error       undefined reference to 'glDeleteShader' PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   128
Error       undefined reference to 'glUseProgram'   PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   172
Error       undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'  PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   174
Error       undefined reference to 'glEnableVertexAttribArray'  PewPew.NativeActivity   c:\workspace\PewPew\PewPew\PewPew.NativeActivity\Renderer.cpp   175
```

Well, it seems to be related to OpenGL calls, but I can't understand how exactly.

I've already included

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
```

But still no luck.

Any suggestions about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, never mind, guys, I've just figured it out all by myself.

This problem appears because I'm trying to use GLES 2.0 Functions, instead of GLES 1.0 (which is set by default when you create new NativeActivity application). So, basically all you need to do is right-click on your project and go Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Library Dependencies and change GLESv1_CM to GLESv2.